# Measuring Rare Earth Element Concentration in a Solution

Tags: elemental-analysis, rare-earth-elements

I am interested in repeating the experiment as detailed in this paper: [Study on Rare Earth Elements Leaching from Magnetic Coal Fly Ash by Citric Acid](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40831-021-00414-7)

In the paper, coal fly ash is leached by citric acid. A sample of the resultant mixture is centrifuged, and the liquid component is filtered and then analyzed to determine the concentration of rare earth elements.

When the solution containing the REEs is fully filtered, how would one measure the concentration of REEs without the use of an atomic spectrometer? I do not have access to expensive laboratory equipment, and was wondering if there is an alternative that would work in my case.

Comment: What instruments are available?

Comment: @AChem Not much, high school lab. Stirrer, hotplate, scale, oven.

Comment: No, then forget about this analysis. Think about a relatively easy project with your teacher. There are plenty of possibilities with simple ideas.

Comment: Rare Earths are notoriously difficult to separate for analysis so this probably cannot be done with high school lab equipment. Ion-exchange chromatography for separation and/or ICP-MS for elemental analysis are the generally accepted methods I believe.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your help. I'll try and come up with another idea to pursue.

Comment: @rubpy32, What about a grating spectroscope in a box for capturing flame emission spectrum in a photograph? You can do wavelength calibration with a simple fluorescent light.

Comment: @AChem Great suggestion! Perhaps you can provide a nice understandable publication the OP might find helpful?

Comment: @EdV, If the OP searches the keywords "shoebox" spectroscope, he/she can find many useful articles. Starting articles could be Wakabayashi, F. Resolving Spectral Lines with a Periscope-Type DVD Spectroscope. J. Chem. Educ. 2008, 85 (6), 849,  DOI: 10.1021/ed085p849.

Comment: Another decent summary is Review of Student-Built Spectroscopy Instrumentation Projects, J. Chem. Educ. 2020, 97, 8, 2185–2195. Plenty of references including some of my own contributions.

Comment: @AChem Will take a look. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have come up with a solution, feel free to self-answer it. Self-answers are appreciated and it helps future readers.